# Python. How do I write a function to find the location of the first occurrence of a substring in a string?

Tags: python, string

I need to write a function that returns the location of the first sub-string in a string in Python without using the `string.find(sub)`

```
def sublocation(string,sub):
    i=0
    while i<len(string):
        o=0
        while o<len(sub):
            u=i
            if string[i] == sub[o]:
                o=o+1
                u=u+1
                result=True
                i=len(string)
            else:
                i=i+1-u
                result=False
```

Comment: use `str.index`. it will help.

Comment: What have you tried so far, and why do you need to write it yourself instead of using an existing python function ?

Comment: Welcome to SO, this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: def sub_search_location(string,sub_string):
    i=0
    while i<len(string):
        o=0
        while o<len(sub_string):
            u=i
            if string[i] == sub_string[o]:
                o=o+1
                u=u+1
                result=True
                i=len(string)
            else:
                i=i+1-u
                result=False

    return result

Comment: Can you add example input and expected output? How are your strings formatted?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [find()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.find).
Ex:

```
>>> s = "this is the string for finding sub string"
>>> s.find('string')
12
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this :

```
myString = "Hellow World!"
index = str.find(myString, "World")
print(index)
```

And the output was :

```
>>> 
7
>>>
```

Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

I think it might help you to learn how to loop in python. If the sub-strings are separated you can use .split() to split it into a list of sub-strings over which you can iterate natively. 'enumerate' enumerate even gives you the index.

```
def sub_search_location(inp_str,sub_string):
    for pos, sub in enumerate(inp_str.split(' ')):
        if sub_string == sub:
           return pos
    else:
        return False

>>>  sub_search_location("this is the string for finding sub string", "string")
3
```

However this works only for sub strings **without** spaces

```
>>>  sub_search_location("this is the string for finding sub string", "sub string")
False
```

Of course you can use `str.find` as others have recommended, but looking at your code I think you have more important things to learn than just a call to an arbitrary method.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the building-in function find,e.m.,"Hello world".find("world") will return 6.The fuction index can do it too,but it will raise exception when string does not have the substring you search.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the method .find(). It will return an index of the substring that you're trying to find.